What if Perfectly elastic body collides with a perfectly inelastic body?
The doubt I have is basically this title. I know a perfectly elastic body should try to create perfectly elastic collision. A perfectly inelastic body tries to create a perfectly inelastic collision. I mean the perfectly inelastic ball will lose all its energy at once. While the elastic one should bounce back. What I wish to know:

Am I correct, that in such a case, the perfectly elastic will bounce with same KE, while the other one becomes stationary?
Is this possible? I know it's not possible for real matter. But even for ideal case, might there I see a contradiction: The law of Conservation of momentum is violated. Does this simply imply that in complete space (vacuum) a perfectly inelastic body even cannot collide with a perfectly elastic body?
I would not have asked this if I had found it in my book, but it seems a part of the case-wise basics.


"Am I correct, that in such a case, the perfectly elastic will bounce with same KE, while the other one becomes stationary?" this  violates conservation of momentum unless the hard one is infinitely massive

In most cases, it doesn't make sense to divide the components into elastic or inelastic parts.   One material can behave elastically in some situations and inelastically in others.
Instead, we can just say that the interaction (or the collision) is elastic or inelastic.
Lets imagine a steel ball striking a mass of clay.   There will be no rebound.   The interaction is identical to two masses of clay striking each other.   Both interactions are completely inelastic.
While the steel ball may not absorb much energy, it requires a surface if it is to rebound.   The perfectly inelastic material does not afford such a surface.  All the KE is lost in the clay.
A perfectly elastic body can transfer energy.   Imagine a Newton's cradle where a single ball comes to a quick stop when colliding even though it has very low energy losses in the collision.
When it strikes the clay instead, it also transfers its energy.   It just doesn't go into the KE of the clay, but into deformation and heat.

The coefficient of restitution is between two objects. It's not an absolute property of an individual object that can be added.

A previous answer made a good point about the overall collision being elastic or inelastic, not the bodies themselves.  But if you want to think of it that way, a perfectly elastic object could be something hard and/or metallic like a billiard ball.  A perfectly plastic object could be something like jello. You can imagine intuitively that the inelastic material property will dominate the collision and it will be inelastic overall.

Firstly the conservation of energy requires that the energy lost by the inelastic ball be transferred in to some other energy. The inelastic ball will lose its energy, either by transferring it to the inelastic ball or by transferring it to the environment.
The elastic ball may preserve its energy content, implying that the ball may not recieve energy transferred from the inelastic ball ; nor lose energy to the environment or to the inelastic ball...following this the energy lost by the inelastic ball must then be transferred to the environment.
It follows then that from the conservation of momentum, the inelastic ball will have a final momentum value of zero, and the elstic ball will have a final momentum value equal to the intial momentum value.
The energy lost by the inelastic ball may result to the production of heat and sound around the region of collision .
Now suppose this is occurring in a vacuum, what then happens to the energy lost by the inelastic ball? Is a crucial question.
If we assume these balls don't have little mass ( so as to avoid quantum effects) such that they induce spacetime curvature, we find that the energy is transferred to the vacuum.This energy is then distributed on the vacuum of the spacetime.With this distribution of energy,considering also a special relativity conclusion; that the energy of a system is proportional to the mass contained in the system; and noting that mass is a property of matter. Also considering a general relativity conclusion ; the distribution of matter on the spacetime, induces curvature of the spacetime. It follows that this excess energy must induce curvature of the spacetime within the region of collision.
The induced curvature of the spacetime is independent to the mass of the inelastic ball, but strictly depends on the energy ( kinetic energy in particular) lost.
